# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error in code

Tags: python, get

I'm trying to make a login style screen and have the frame behind raised if the password matches I get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` when I run my program :

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    entry = "placeholder"
    def framechange(self):
        if self.entry.get() == "password":
            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne")
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        entry = tk.Entry(self, show="•")
        entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",command = self.framechange)
        button1.pack()
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no `get()` requests called from inside the class. Also, you are missing a `self` in your input statement:

Try:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    entry = "placeholder"
    def framechange(self):
        if self.entry == "password": # Changed
            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne")
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, show="•") # Changed
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, padx=10) # Changed
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Login",command = self.framechange)
        button1.pack()
```

Comment: It's not doing anything when the login button is pressed, I think this is because there's nothing taking information from the entry field for the command in button 1

Comment: @user217591 Did not know you forgot `self`.